# tkinter code giving "SyntaxError: illegal target for annotation"

Tags: python, tkinter

I am running a script from [here](https://www.educba.com/tkinter-slider/):

```
from tkinter import *
defshowval(): print (sli1.get())
parent = Tk()
parent.geometry("500x500")
sli1 = Scale(parent, from_=10, to=100, tickinterval=10, orient=HORIZONTAL, bg = "RED")
sli1.place(relx=0.15,rely=0.06,relwidth=10)
sli1.pack()
Button(parent, text='click me !!', command=showval).pack()
mainloop()
```

using Python 3.7.6 on Spyder, and tk is version 8.6.

The script gives me this:

```
SyntaxError: illegal target for annotation
```

Not understanding this error, I have tried modifying the backend--Tkinter, Qt4, Qt5, and restarting the console each time.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question? The title mentions one error, the question mentions another, and neither are generated by the code you've posted.

Comment: `defshowval(): print (sli1.get())` should be `def showval(): print(sli1.get())`.  Also calling `place()` and `pack()` together is meaningless as `pack()` will override `place()` effect.  The code will not produce the `AttributeError` mentioned in question.

Comment: @BryanOakley I copied the wrong error. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is caused by the line:

```py
defshowval(): print (sli1.get())
```

It should be:

```
def showval():
    print(sli1.get())
```

Also calling `place()` and `pack()` on `sli1` is meaningless as the later one will override the former one.  Choose either one.

Comment: Please read [answer] and do not attempt to answer questions that are obviously caused by a typo. They are not suitable for the site, and answering them interferes with automatic cleanup processes.